# Getting the kernel ID and ram disk ID from aws instance or ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, kernel, amazon-ami, ramdisk

I have an aws instance and if I look at it from the console or use the aws describe command, there doesn't seem to be a valid kernel ID or ram disk ID. Looking at the ami I used to create the instance results in the same thing.

How can I find out what the kernel ID and ram disk IDs are? I am trying to make a new ami from a volume and it seems like the default kernel ID and ram disk ID don't work and need to know the actual values for my running instance.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel ID and Ramdisk ID properties are only applicable to Linux AMI images. Maybe this can help you to get your answer :
[+] https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=289146

AWS would not recommend that you play around with kernel images until you have read the following documentation http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedkernels.html

Also it has been suggest that you test on non production systems so as not to impact your business.